# Should a tag creator be able to edit the tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

Should the creator of a tag be able to edit the tag wiki?

**Background:** Recently, Ether added the `goatse` tag to [Is the Perl Goatse 'Secret Operator' efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991766/is-the-perl-goatse-secret-operator-efficient), and I asked her whether she's going to write up the tag wiki, and she noted that she can't.

Creating tags without wikis would be adding to the backlog of writing up tag wikis.

Apologies for the lack of hand created circles: upvotes will be awarded for them.

Comment: Of all the tags you could've possibly picked as your example, you went with [goatse]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the love of all that is good in this world can we **not** have a tag wiki for goatse.

<strike>Top 20 answerers for any tag can always edit wikis, provided they meet the rep threshold. I do not see any reason to extend this to tag creators or askers.</strike>

Registered users can suggest creation or editing of tag wikis.

Comment: This. Popular usage or not, its just asking for controversy.

Comment: @dmckee: Is this the "Colour of the goatshed" effect?

Comment: ether should know better than this

Comment: @Andrew: No. It's a "really nasty internet meme" effect. Search it if you dare (not from work!), but don't say I didn't warn you. There are some things that can't be unseen.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm familiar with what `goatse` is. I was jokingly asking whether "The colour of the bikeshed" effect means that it gets more attention than other tags.

Comment: @Jeff: Was that joking or serious?

Comment: @Andrew: yeah, I can't tell if he's joking either. I admit I added the tag somewhat for the amusement factor, but I wouldn't have added it on an irrelevant question. After all, *that really is the name for the pseudo-operator `=()=`.*

Comment: ...e.g. documentation for it can be found here: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/secret-perl-operators and http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=527973.

Answer (score 1):

This tag has made me believe tag wikis should be restricted to tags with a minimum number of questions.  I'm thinking 20-50.

And the creator shouldn't get any special privileges, they are already eligible for Taxonomist.  If they're also knowledgeable in that tag (and post on the site to prove it), then they can edit the wiki.

Comment: If you think the tag is inappropriate, then shouldn't it be banned, rather than merely lack a wiki?

Comment: @Andrew: I'm not saying it's inappropriate.  I'm saying we don't need to even worry about tag wikis until a tag has a certain minimum level of use.  On SO in particular, any tag with less than 50 uses is nearly worthless for searching, sorting, and categorizing — in fact, the only value it has is that it may one day be used more. :)

Comment: @Roger: I think I've found rarely-used tags useful, but I can't remember right now when I found it useful.

Comment: @Andrew: Perhaps 50 is too high even for SO, but I think we'd agree that the more use a tag has (correct use, of course), the more valuable it gets for searching/sorting/related-sidebar/ignoring/etc.; with a long plateau after a few hundred uses (e.g. [c++] is valuable, [c++0x] less so, but still valuable, and both make [goatse] look insignificant).

Comment: @Roger: I'd say that `[c++]` would only be useful if you had other search terms.

Comment: @Andrew: The hugely popular tags like [c++] are useful for new/unanswered questions (including feeds) and to filter out questions you have no interest in.

Comment: This would cause problems for sites like [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com), which sometimes only have 2 or 3 questions per tag. (Ex: [mario-kart-8-deluxe](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mario-kart-8-deluxe), [tony-hawks-pro-skater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tony-hawks-pro-skater), [tharsis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tharsis)). I'd argue tag wikis are even more important for obscure smaller, as users are less likely to understand the tag's subject matter.