# Tag Wiki for a new tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

So (shockingly) I created a new [tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pii) and rushed over to tag page to explain [what the heck this tag means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information).  Sadly I could not edit it.

What should I do?

(I think the "creator" of a tag, and maybe users with say > 3,000k rep, should be able to edit the wiki prior to the tag (and any given user) hitting the magic edit count).

Comment: or at least a basic summary, and leave the specialized detail / FAQ for the top 20 or 100+ as now.

Comment: A feature request for the tag creator to edit the wiki was provided [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68414/should-a-tag-creator-be-able-to-edit-the-tag-wiki). As noted there, people who answer a question with a new tag are basically automatically in the top 20... which includes you! But it just hasn't updated yet. The stats updates at roughly the end of the day, I believe, at which point you should be able to edit the tag wiki yourself. I say just wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed, anyone can suggest an edit for any tag wiki now, including brand new ones.

Comment: I created a tag [`html-heading`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-heading) and am also retaging related questions. But I can't seem to edit the tag's wiki or suggest one. Can you tell me why?